# MongoDB: While using triggers, Document fails validation for int type

Tags: mongodb, triggers, mongodb-atlas

I am using mongodb `triggers` for automated update of `courses_count` in student collection.

My **student** collection is as:

[image: Student Collection]

Validation rule for `student` collection is defined as:

```
{
  $jsonSchema: {
    required: [
      'name',
      'email',
      'password',
      'dob',
      'address'
    ],
    properties: {
      name: {
        bsonType: 'string'
      },
      email: {
        bsonType: 'string'
      },
      password: {
        bsonType: 'string'
      },
      dob: {
        bsonType: 'date'
      },
      address: {
        bsonType: 'string'
      },
      courses_count: {
        bsonType: [
          'int',
          'double',
          'decimal'
        ]
      }
      courses: {
        bsonType: 'array',
        items: {
          required: [
            '_id',
            'is_completed',
            'is_certified'
          ],
          properties: {
            _id: {
              bsonType: 'objectId'
            },
            name: {
              bsonType: 'string'
            },
            is_free: {
              bsonType: 'bool'
            },
            is_completed: {
              bsonType: 'bool'
            },
            is_certified: {
              bsonType: 'bool'
            },
           }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can clearly see, I've defined `courses_count` to be `int`,`double`or`decimal`

I have defined `courses_count_trigger` in mongodb atlas as:

```js
exports = async function(changeEvent) {
  const { fullDocument } = changeEvent;
  const mongodb = context.services.get("vidly");
  const docId = changeEvent.documentKey._id;
  
  var courses_count= 0;
  
  if(fullDocument.courses){
    courses_count=fullDocument.courses.length;
  }
  
  return mongodb.db("coursera").collection("student").updateOne({_id:docId},{ $set:{courses_count: courses_count}});
}
```

It's fine when there are some courses in my student collection.
It updates correctly using `fullDocument.courses.length`.

[image: Trigger OK Status if courses array is there]

But when there are no courses , it fails to update the document.
i.e. it fails the validation.
[image: Validation Failed if no courses]

I have also checked:

`typeof(fullDocument.courses.length)` gives `number`.

`typeof(0)` is obviously `number`.

Why does it fails validation? Please help.

Comment: When there are no documents, the filter within the update {_id: docId}, will return no document to update.

Comment: There are document for `student` collection.
But, in case when there are no courses(or courses array) within the student `collection`.
It won't take `courses_count = 0`. Since 0 is an integer, it shouldn't show validation error. 
But,it does.